# How to backup contacts when my touchscreen is cracked?

Tags: lock-screens, touchscreen, locked-out, broken-screen, pattern-lock

My touchscreen on my Samsung Galaxy screen is cracked. I am unable to use the screen. It has a pattern lock. When I use Kies 3 it says that my phone is locked. How do I unlock it with the pattern password enabled?

Comment: Hint for first readings: our tag-wikis contain first-aid help and good links on the topic. See for [locked-out](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) and [broken-screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info).

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can't unlock that even you slide your fingers on the screen, unless you will repair that with new ones.


 And if you want your password to be removed, then follow these steps 
**Note**: Your phone's buttons (volumes, home and power) must be functional.

  #### Reboot into recovery
- Turn off your phone, After it's completely off
  Hold and press power and volume up button together, this will bring you to your recovery.

  **Note**: Different phone have different key configuration to access recovery mode, for now we'll be using the most common key combination. If it doesn't work for you, you must search on google on how you can access your recovery mode, be sure to include your phone model in your searches.
- Once you are in the recovery mode, you see some kind of options and the one that we will be using is.

  1. **Wipe data/factory reset** - is a feature that erases all device settings, user data, third-party applications, and associated application data from an Android device's internal flash storage to return the device to the condition it was in when shipped from the factory.
  2. **Backup User Data** (optional) - this method backups the following:

     - Google Calendar settings
     - Wi-Fi networks & passwords
     - Home screen wallpapers
     - Gmail settings
     - Apps installed through Google Play (backed up on the Play Store app)
     - Display settings (Brightness & Sleep)
     - Language & Input settings
     - Date & Time
     - Third-party app settings & data (varies by app)

     **Restore User Data** (optional) - It will restore the data through the backed up data
- Choose Backup User Data if you want to restore your data anytime
  **Note**: This may restore your screen lock (password, pattern or PIN)
- To remove your password, select Wipe data/Factory reset, this will also remove everything in your phone, and restore to it's original state just like the first time you used it after buying

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Google account or a Samsung account, your contacts should be backed up already. Log into your accounts online to check.

If not, the simplest option, if you know your pattern password and more importantly, ***if you can see the screen enough to see the pattern, just can't touch it***, is to use a OTG-USB adapter, and a USB mouse. The mouse can be used to unlock the pattern lock.